# term-by-term differentiation of function series $\frac{d}{dx}( \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} f_{k}(x))=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}( \frac{d}{dx}f_{k}(x) ) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, derivatives, power-series

> I wonder How do I write that equality legally?
>
> $$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} f_{k}(x)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(  \dfrac{d}{dx}f_{k}(x)  \right)  $$

indeed,

- In case of $f_{k}$ are power series we can under these conditions :

[image]
[Power Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation)

- In case of sum is finit and $f_{k}$ are différentiable we can write :

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{n} f_{k}(x)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(  \dfrac{d}{dx}f_{k}(x)  \right)$$
In other words, the derivative of any finite sum of functions is the sum of the derivatives of those functions.

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_rule_in_differentiation)

- What is the condition which let us to write that :

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} f_{k}(x)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left(  \dfrac{d}{dx}f_{k}(x)  \right)  $$

could we use that theorem to write it

[image]

- also friend of mine told me that's why we were built the first continuous functions but nowhere differentiable but i didn't understand it, here is link :
  [continuous functions but nowhere differentiable](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_continue_nulle_part_d%C3%A9rivable)

Comment: The answer is contained in the theorem you quote. If the series of functions converges pointwise and the series of derivatives converges uniformly, then the series is differentiable, and the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives.

Comment: could you give me some some books/references  to that theorem in english please

Answer (score 4):

Another answer is Fubini's less-famous theorem
[LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem_on_differentiation) where the functions $f_k$ are increasing.